# ¿Porque da un "Error 1005: Can't create table"?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Estoy intendao crear una tabla mediante "foward engineering" pero continuamente salta el error siguiente:

> Executing SQL script in server
> ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `u807244066_crm1`.`relacion_direcciones` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
 -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `u807244066_crm1`.`relacion_direcciones`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `u807244066_crm1`.`relacion_direcciones` (
      `idrelacion_direccion` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
      `idcliente` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
      `idcontacto` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
      `iddireccion` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idrelacion_direccion`),
      INDEX `idcliente_idx` (`idcliente` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `idcontacto_idx` (`idcontacto` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `relacionDireccionesIdDirecciones_idx` (`iddireccion` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `relacionDireccionesIdCliente`
        FOREIGN KEY (`idcliente`)
        REFERENCES `u807244066_crm1`.`clientes` (`idcliente`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `relacionDireccionesIdDirecciones`
        FOREIGN KEY (`iddireccion`)
        REFERENCES `u807244066_crm1`.`direcciones` (`iddireccion`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `relacionDireccionesIdContacto`
        FOREIGN KEY (`idcontacto`)
        REFERENCES `u807244066_crm1`.`contactos` (`idcontacto`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: ¿Has hecho [esta búsqueda](/search?q=Error+1005+%5Bmysql%5D) en el sitio? ¿O [esta otra](/search?q=1005+[mysql-workbench])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más probable es que no hayas indexado los campos de las tablas referenciadas. Prueba con alguna de estas instrucciones antes de lanzar nuevamente el `CREATE TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE contactos ADD INDEX(idcontacto);
ALTER TABLE direcciones ADD INDEX(iddireccion);
ALTER TABLE clientes ADD INDEX(idcliente);
```